# Overzealous "Remember my Password" in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I had Firefox "remember my password" for my site, and I have a screen that allows me to create a new user, so it has inputs for username and password.  These inputs are named something entirely different than what's on the login page, yet they are being filled in by Firefox.  The same behavior does not happen in Chrome.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Login page:

```
<label for="UserName">User name</label>
<input id="UserName" type="text" name="UserName" data-val-required="The User name field is required." data-val="true" class="valid">
```

Create User page:

```
<label for="NewUserNameForCreation">User name</label>
<input id="NewUserNameForCreation" type="text" name="NewUserNameForCreation" data-val-required="The User name field is required." data-val="true" class="valid">
```

Comment: This is not caused by "Remember My Password", it is a feature of the browser. @Kevin's solution would prevent the browser from auto-populating the field.

Comment: Actually it is caused by "Remember My Password" and not `autocomplete`, because if I tell Firefox to forget the remembered password for my site, it no longer happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this behavior myself, but have you tried adding the `autocomplete` attribute to your `input`?

```
<input id="NewUserNameForCreation" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="NewUserNameForCreation" data-val-required="The User name field is required." data-val="true" class="valid">
```

Comment: `autocomplete` will fix it, depending on the version of Firefox being run (determining whether or not Firefox respects that HTML spec or not).  But should it even be happening?  I mean, the names aren't even close to the same.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if `autocomplete` would fix it, because if I tell Firefox to forget the remembered password for my site, it no longer happens.

Answer (score 0):

After you changed your password, the OLD password is no longer valid. You must use the NEW password to access your account, regardless of the browser you use.

Many site issues can be caused by corrupt cookies or cache. In order to try to fix these problems, the first step is to clear both cookies and the cache. Note: This will temporarily log you out of all sites you're logged in to. To clear cache and cookies do the following:

1) Go to Firefox > History > Clear recent history or (if no Firefox button is shown) go to Tools > Clear recent history.

2 )Under "Time range to clear", select "Everything".

3)Now, click the arrow next to Details to toggle the Details list active.
From the details list, check Cache and Cookies and uncheck everything else.

4)Now click the Clear now button.
Further information can be found in the [Clear your cache, history and other personal information in Firefox article](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cache-history-and-personal-information).

Did this fix your problems? Please report back to us!

Thanks!!![